# Calulating and graphing data from a .pdf with ruby (+ rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm really stuck on this. Don't even know where to start. So I've got this .pdf, which has 2 columns, the first one is the lets say member ID. The second one is the number of purchases they have made. Is it possible to match the ID to the correct number and graph this data, and afterwards make calculations with the acquired and matched data (Calculate top  5% of buyers etc.)? Some numbers are not filled in, so that might be a problem. However, the pdf's are selectable and if copy&pasted will have the following structure: userid number userid number userid number userid number userid number.

EDIT: Making calculations with the data (calculating the top x%, ranks etc. will be the most important)

Any help, tips or links to tutorials that even might help me are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use prawn.
Here are some links to get you started:

1. [Prawn github page](https://github.com/sandal/prawn)
2. [Using-Prawn-in-Rails](https://github.com/sandal/prawn/wiki/Using-Prawn-in-Rails)
3. and, look for **Prawn Templates**.

EDIT:
Check out these links:
[pdfescape](http://www.pdfescape.com/)
[pdfedit](http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html)
and Do look out for a templating solution, if it's there.
Also look here, you might find something useful:
[whats-the-best-way-to-programmatically-edit-a-pdf-in-ruby](http://pathfindersoftware.com/2009/07/whats-the-best-way-to-programmatically-edit-a-pdf-in-ruby/)

As I have not dealt with such problem mysqlf, I can only help you this much. You have to do the hard work yourself.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Skimmed over the prawn manual real quick, so excuse me if I'm wrong. From what i read, prawn is used to generate pdfs, while I need to GET the data from the .pdf and output the calculations (like the top 5% customers), in whatever format possible.